# How can I equip the universal vector bundle over $\mathbf{G}(k,n)$ with a connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

When constructing the grassmannians $\mathbf{G}_\mathbb{F}(k,n)$ for $\mathbb{F} = \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C} \}$ there is a natural vector bundle
$$
\mathbf{G}_{k,n} \to \mathbf{G}_\mathbb{F}(k,n)
$$
whose fiber over a point $[V]$ is the vector space $V$. Is there a natural connection I can equip to this bundle? Also, in the complex case, is there a natural holomorphic connection?

Comment: The bundle natually sits inside the trivial bundle $G(k,n) \times \mathbb R^n$. Then define (As Ted Shifrin suggested) $\nabla s = (Ds)^\perp$, where $(\cdot)^\perp$ denotes the projection onto $G_{k,n}$. and $D$ is a standard connection on the trivial bundle.

Comment: I meant to use $(\cdot)^\top$ in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do the analogue of the Levi-Civita connection for submanifolds of Euclidean space. Differentiate a section (as an $\Bbb F^n$-valued function) and project orthogonally onto the subspace.

Comment: I haven't seen this before. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I've taught this in graduate courses plenty of times, but I do not have a reference off the top of my head.